# Find view in dynamically added layouts

Tags: java, android

So I have a layout with an Add button, which when clicked adds a custom layout to the LinearLayout.

In this custom layout, I have an image, that when clicked should increase a counter (displayed in a textView next to the image).

The problem I am currently having is, that when I have more than one custom layout added, and I click the image it always increases the count of the textView right on top and not the textView next to the image clicked.

How would I find the correct textView to change?

I am fairly new to the android dev world, so if I am doing anything wrong please add that too.

Regards

Comment: Post your code and you'll get a response more quickly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `OnClickListener` to each `ImageView` when you're inflating your custom layout. In this listener refer to a final `TextView` variable which repesents a `TextView` exactly from the currently created layout. Something like this:

```
    private void addView() {
        View customView = getLayoutInflater.inflate(resId, null);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        customView.findViewById(R.id.imageview).setOnClickListener(new OnClickLitener(View v) {
            textView.setText("value");
        });
        container.addView(customView);
    }
```

Comment: I will give this a shot, but what do you mean by "refer to a **final** TextView"